# How to decrease touchpad area of contact required?

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

I can use my touchpad with my thumb, but not with my short finger. It is as if the area of contact between the fingers and the pad required to register movement/click is too large. How do I fix this?

Output of xinput shows three pointer devices:

```
Virtual Core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ALPS PS/2 Device                          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Output of `uname -r`

```
3.16.0-45-generic
```

output of `xinput` after kernel upgrade:

```
emmanuel@emmanuel-HP-14-Notebook-PC:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ALPS PS/2 Device                          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Truevision HD                          id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

- [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12021680/)'s the output of `xinput list-props 11`

Output of `dmesg | grep pnp`:

```
[    0.776582] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.776830] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.776924] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs HPQ8001 PNP0303 (active)
[    0.776956] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs AUI1712 PNP0f13 (active)
[    0.846687] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 7 devices
```

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and add output of `uname -r` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've updated the question.

Comment: Is `GlidePoint` the touchpad? Then please post output of `xinput list-props 11`. You can find out which is the touchpad by trying `xinput disable 11` or `xinput disable 12`. The one that stops touchpad from working is that. You can `enable` them back.

Comment: @Pilot6 It's `GlidePoint(id=11)` I've added output to the question.

Comment: I think this is a kernel driver issue. Try kernel 4.1 or 4.2 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: @Pilot6, we tried 4.1 and it's still there...

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep pnp` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 I need a solution for this other than carrying around a USB mouse. I've added the output of dmesg to the question. Thanx

Comment: This looks like a kernel driver problem. This should be reported as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am convinced with a solution that provided by ubuntu community as it worked for my ubuntu 14.04 (on hp14-notebookpc).It is just adjusting the sensitivity as follows,

Open a terminal and `xinput list` and note down your pointer device number.

Setting sensitivity:

Apply `xinput --set-prop [device number] "Synaptics Finger" 50 80 257`(use values that suits).Now the sensitivity will be readjusted.
The higher you set the numbers the more force is needed to make an event fire. And the less sensitive the touchpad get.For the accurate information visit "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad".